# Error reading Firestore data from flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
getData() async{
    var result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('documentId').get();
    print(result['']);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

In, if the value in `result['']` is `aa` or `1aa`, the data can be read, but if it is `1.aa`, it cannot be read. How do I solve this?

```
error code is [VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform
#0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findKeyValueInMap (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:87:7)
#1      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findComponent (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:105:23)
#2      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:121:12)
#3      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:92:48)
#4      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.[] (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:96:40)
#5      _jiujitsu_CalState.getData (package:el_sports/JiuJitsu_Page/jiujitsu_cal_page.dart:18:17)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I tested the `result['']` value with `aa` and `1aa`.

How can I bring up the `result['1. email']`?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Added database screenshot successfully


https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSbkR.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're using the `.` (dot) character inside the name of the field. Please note that the dot is used as a separator between maps that exist within Cloud Firestore documents. To solve this, stop using the dot within field names. If you need some kind of order, then I recommend you change the following key:

```
1. email
```

to:

```
1_email
```

And your error will go away.

Besides that, I cannot see a document that has an ID set to `documentId`. As also @MrShakila mentioned in his answer, in order to be able to read the document you have to pass the exact document ID that exists in the database to the `doc()` function:

```
var result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('ox...wI').get();
//
```

Answer (score 0):

In here use a real document id instead of word

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('ox......')//use your id
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't wanna set the field name using that format which contains some characters such as "." or whitespaces. That's not a proper naming practice for database fields.

I think the error message is telling that it is looking for the field called `email` which is subfield of the field `1` which is not existent.